# Receiving "InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lng: not a number" error even though the values are numbers

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to initialize a map using the Google Maps API. Input the latitude and longitude for the center as numbers. Receiving an error that says they are not numebrs.

```
var map; // Variable used to create new map
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('ippudo-map'); // Location of the map in the html

// Create a function to initialize the map

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: {lat: 42.3601, long: 71.0589},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

Comment: Didi you solve it? I am getting this error even if I parseFloat() the values. Can't figure out why....

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google Maps JavaScript API documentation the `LatLngLiteral` interface has two fields: `lat` and `lng`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral

In your example you are using `long` instead of `lng`. You should fix the wrong field name

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: 42.3601, lng: 71.0589},
        zoom: 8
    });
}
```

I hope this helps!